# For any sentence A, if M $\models$ A , then M' $\models$ A as well

Tags: first-order-logic

Exact problem in words:

Let $M$ be an interpretation, and let $M′$ be an extension of $M$. Prove that, for any sentence $A$, if $M$$\models$$A$, then M′ $\models$ $A$.

I'm having trouble here because can't the extension of M' be true while M is false?

For example, taking the sentence $A$: $\exists$$x$(P($x$) $\cap$ R($a$))

So, I make an interpretation $M$ for $A$ where:

$|M|$ = {$1, 2$}

$M^P$ = {$2$}

$M^R$ = {$1$}

$M(a) = 2$

And construct an extension of $M$, $M'$, with the same domain and predicate extensions of $M$, but assigning $a$ a different object from the domain, namely

$M'(a) = 1$

Then, I see that $M$ $\models$$A$. But wouldn't the extension $M'$ be false, because $2$ $\notin$ $M^R$ $?$ Would this not provide proof that the original statement is indeed false? I'm asked to prove this statement for an assignment, so it must be true, so I must not be understanding how extensions of interpretations work, or my definition of $\models$ is wonky. Any insight into what i'm not getting would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the situation you've described, $M'$ **is not** an extension of $M$: to be an extension, $M'$ must agree with $M$ on all the symbols in the language of $M$ (in particular here, it can't send $a$ to somewhere other than where $M$ sends $a$).

The idea is that $M'$ *adds structure to* the existing structure of $M$. For example, the structure $A=(\mathbb{Z}; +,\times)$ is an extension of the structure $B=(\mathbb{Z};+)$: they have the same domain and each interpret the "$+$" symbol in the same way, but $A$ has an *additional* bit of structure, namely multiplication.

---

Of course, above I'm being a bit fast and loose with the distinction between a *symbol* and a *function* (or relation, or constant). Really it would be more precise to say:

> "Let $\oplus,\otimes$ be binary function symbols, let $\Sigma=\{\oplus\}$, and let $\Pi=\{\oplus,\otimes\}$. Let $A$ be the $\Sigma$-structure with domain $\mathbb{Z}$ and which interprets $\oplus$ as $+$, and let $B$ be the $\Pi$-structure with domain $\mathbb{Z}$ which interprets $\oplus$ as $+$ and $\otimes$ as $\times$.  Then $A$ and $B$ have the same domain, the language of $A$ is contained in the language of $B$, and $A$ and $B$ agree on the interpretations of everything in their shared language (namely, just $\oplus$ in this case); so $B$ is an extension of $A$."

But that's a bit long, and I think the way I wrote it above is more intuitive.

---

Incidentally, if you're familiar with abstract algebra, there's a very general kind of extension you've seen before: a **ring** is an extension of its underlying **group**. If you're not familiar with abstract algebra, ignore this bit, but if you are this might help make the notion of extension seem more natural.

Comment: So if i say for $M'$ that it sends $a$ to the set {$1,2$}, then $M'$ would be considered a valid extension?

Comment: @MattyS11 A structure can't send a constant symbol to a set, it has to send it to a *single element*. Again, $M'$ is an extension of $M$ iff the interpretation in $M'$ of each of the symbols in the language of $M$ is **exactly the same as** the interpretation of that symbol in $M$. $M'$ needs to be identical to $M$ except as far as any *new* symbols (= symbols in the language of $M'$ but not in the language of $M$) are concerned.

Comment: right right sorry im dumb lol. So M'(a) would HAVE to map to 2 in this case, but could also send any other constant symbol x to any element of the domain.

Comment: @MattyS11 Yes - as long as such an other constant symbol wasn't in the language of $M$ already.